# becomeFirstResponder works in viewDidAppear but doesn't work in viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

My Application has a modal view controller, including a search bar. When the view comes up, I want the search bar to be focused. I tried `[self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder]` in `viewDidLoad`, but it didn't work. Later on I put it in `viewDidAppear`, it worked. But with this workaround, there is a visible delay. (after the view fully appeared, the keyboard began to appear)

I can ensure both `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidLoad` have been invoked.

What should I do if I want the search bar to be focused instantly with the view appear?

(I'm using StoryBoard)

Followed the answers, I tried to put the code in `viewWillLoad`, but still didn't work. (in `viewWillLoad`, `self.searchBar.window` is nil)

Comment: Where r u initiating your searchbar?

Comment: Did you try to put [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder] into viewWillAppear ? It's called after viewDidLoad, but while viewController not visible yet

Comment: @roronoazorro: I'm using StoryBoard.

Comment: @Mikhail: I tried, doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

You should call in viewDidLayoutSubviews(), the code below set textField becomeFirstResponder only at the first time view layout subviews, and it should be.

```
var isFirstLayout: Bool = true
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if isFirstLayout {
        defer { isFirstLayout = false }
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Possibly it does not work in viewDidLoad, as view does not added into view hierarchy yet. But according to apple documentation becomeFirstResponder should be called only on objects attached to UIWindow:

```
However, you should only call it on that view if it is part of a view hierarchy. 
If the view’s window property holds a UIWindow object, it has been installed 
in a view hierarchy; if it returns nil, the view is detached from any hierarchy.
```

So, i assume, the best place to achieve necessary behavior is to place call into `viewWillAppear` method.

**Update.**

So, in viewWillAppear controller's view not yet attached to UIWindow... it only notify, that view will be added to view hierarchy

It may be some tricky, but you can make some small delay in viewWillAppear:

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    double delayInSeconds = 0.05;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
        make first responder here
    });
 }
```

But I believe there is should be a better solution

Comment: Maybe subclass the view and override `didMoveToWindow` ?

Answer (score 4):

all the IBOutlet objects are loaded in viewDidLoad,if  you are calling the method in viewDidLoad then that action not performed because before the objects are loaded we can't do anything that's whybetter to write that code in

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
//write here
}
```

then it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

This will help:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.quantifyTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    });
}
```

Comment: Magic numbers and delays are just a bad idea in general.

Comment: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self.quantifyTextField becomeFirstResponder]; });`

Comment: Another option: `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { [textField] in textField.becomeFirstResponder() }`

Answer (score 2):

Making text field/view first responder should be done after all UIViewController animations, which take place when view is loaded and presented. So the best place is viewDidAppear.

Comment: "Note: Make sure that your app has established its object graph before assigning an object to be the first responder. For example, you typically call the becomeFirstResponder method in an override of the viewDidAppear: method. If you try to assign the first responder in viewWillAppear:, your object graph is not yet established, so the becomeFirstResponder method returns NO.
" - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html

Answer (score 1):

Write `viewWillAppear` instad of `viewDidAppear/viewDidLoad`.

Because`viewWillAppear` method is call at the time of View will appear (*in process*), for more information [about `viewWillAppear` read this official Document.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: @XhackerLiu- i putted code after try in my application ..here is worked properly :)

Comment: Thanks. In my situation, in viewWillAppear, `self.searchBar.window` is still nil. Do you know something about it?

Comment: check ..properly connected with file's owner ??

Comment: u mean add search bar programattically ??

Comment: then this code is proper ...i think mistake in other phase :)

Comment: @XhackerLiu- +1 for u ,,all the best..keep it up :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a bit old thread, but I think it can help someone that is facing some keyboard issue when adding this code.

Remember to set the textfield delegate to nil in viewWillDisappear, otherwise the keyboard will not be shown again if you pop/dismiss the view controller without closing the keyboard.