# Keyboard Appearing WIthout Animation First Time TextView Becomes First Responder in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextview, becomefirstresponder

I have a textview that the first time it becomes first responder after the view controller loads, the keyboard does not animate into position. Instead, it instantly appears without animation.  The second, third and so on times, the keyboard does animate in the normal way.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?

I could only find [one question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767698/keyboard-appearing-without-animation-on-ios-5) about this and it does not have an accepted answer.

The only I can think of is that it has something to do with the process by which views are layed out. I am using autolayout. However, since animation of keyboards is a system property, I can't think of any way to "turn on" animation for the keyboard.

I have tried the following in textviewDidBegin editing as well as viewdidload but it has no effect.

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

What could be causing this?  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Try setting it as first responder inside `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`. Had something similar back in the days too.
EDIT: Seems to be something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472784/becomefirstresponder-works-in-viewdidappear-but-doesnt-work-in-viewdidload). `viewDidLayoutSubviews` might work too.

Comment: Also make sure you call it from Main thread

Comment: Right now the view is becoming a first responder upon tap, not programmatically. These are good ideas but not sure how to implement in this case